# Let $X\sim\mathrm{Exp}(1),Y\sim\mathrm{Exp}(2)$ independent random variables. Let $Z = \min(X, Y)$. Calculate $E(Z^2)$.

Tags: probability

Exercise:

> Let $X\sim\mathrm{Exp}(1)$, $Y\sim\mathrm{Exp}(2)$ independent random variables. Let $Z = \min(X, Y)$. Calculate $E(Z^2)$.

What is the approach for such question? What is the way to solve it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Unfortunately there are two distinct conventional meanings of $Y\sim\mathrm{Exp}(2)$: it can mean the expected value is $2$, or that the intensity is $2$, so that the expected value is $1/2$.  Which did you intend here?

Comment: @MichaelHardy X is random variable which distributes exponentially

Comment: I understand that very well, but it doesn't address the question.  Did you mean an exponentially distributed random variable with expected value $2$ or one with expected value $1/2$?

Comment: @MichaelHardy A random variable with density $f_X(t)=2e^{-2t}$.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff : So it would have expected value $1/2$.  But you're not the original poster.  How do you know he didn't mean expected value $2$?  I.e. $F_X(x) = (1/2)e^{-x/2}$ for $x>0$? ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: The notation is standard for what the OP just said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: $P(Z \ge z) = P(X \ge z) P(Y \ge z)$.  Find the distribution of $Z$.